# Loop through a list of checkboxes, if checked, populate the text of the checkbox to a certian excel cell

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a C# WinForm application. There are many checkboxes, I want to check if any of them is checked, if so, print the text that the checkbox has to an Excel cell. I think I need to create a List of something. The below code is what I have right now, it's definitely not gonna work, just to give you an idea where I want to go. Thanks in advance!

```
int j = 0;
                            if (checkBox7.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox8.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox9.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox10.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox11.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox12.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox13.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox14.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox15.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox16.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox17.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox18.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox24.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox42.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox43.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox44.Checked) j++;
                            if (checkBox45.Checked) j++;

                            for (int m = j; m < 17; m++)
                            {
                                NewExcelWorkSheet.Cells[ProductReturnRawData.Count + 10 + m, 1] = Convert.ToString(CheckBox[j].checked.Text);
                            }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a CheckedListBox control?

Comment: Not yet, would you please elaborate or give me an example?

Comment: What's the logic for the filling `Text` into `Excel cells`? at least you should talk a little about the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locke's suggestion of using a CheckedListBox makes sense, but if you absolutely can't, you'll have to do something like this:

```
if(checkBox7.Checked)
    doSomethingWith(checkBox7.Text);
```

etc. I can't tell what you're trying to do with the NewExcelWorkSheet just from looking at it, because the result won't be consistent.

To create a string list of the selected text:

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>;
if(checkBox7.Checked)
    myStringList.Add(checkBox7.Text);
if(checkBox8.Checked)
    myStringList.Add(checkBox8.Text);
```

etc. Then, once you're done all 17 checkboxes, do a foreach iteration on the list to move it into the NewExcelWorkSheet. Note you could transfer it straight into the NewExcelWorkSheet and skip making the list entirely, of course.

Comment: Because I don't want to leave empty cells in the Excel sheet. Without the list and if (.checked) function, I have to keep a place holder (a cell) for each checkbox, in case the user doesn't check the checkbox, that cell would be empty. So I need to create a list and determine which checkbox's text will be printed to excel cell. Clear enough?

Comment: Kind of. In that case, just declare the starting Excel index (you seem to want to start at 10 for some reason) at the top, then increment it inside each if's code block if you're going to skip the myStringList; otherwise inside the foreach iteration at the end.

Comment: Somehow this code only print the text of the last checkbox that is checked....foreach (string period in PeriodCheckBoxList)
                                {
                                    int j = 0;
                                        NewExcelWorkSheet.Cells[ProductReturnRawData.Count + 10 + j, 1] = period;
                                    j++;
                                }

Comment: Put your `int j = 0` call before the foreach statement and you should be fine. If you keep it inside, j will always be 0 when you use it. `int j=0; foreach (string period in PeriodCheckBoxList) { /*etc. etc.*/ }`